# Colorize typing into iex shell

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

Is it possible to colorize typing into elixir interactive shell (iex) ?

```
iex [21:13 :: 2] > quote do: 1 + 2
{:+, [context: Elixir, import: Kernel], [1, 2]}
```

So, this part

> quote do: 1 + 2

is always white (I cannot set different color for *quote* or *do:*). All others can be colored using *.iex.exs* config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither Elixir nor Erlang shell support colouring dynamic input, so what you want to achieve is not possible with current implementation.